# Recursive folder action

Tags: macos, terminal

For the files in a folder I'm using

```
for file in *.wav; do sox "$file" "n_$file" silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse; done
```

I want to strip silence all the files in sub & subsub folders. I want the strip silenced versions in the same folder as originals.

The code I use just does it inside the current folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *may* work, depending on exactly how your version of the `find` command works. It should work with the version that comes with macOS, but I don't think it'll work with GNU `find`. You should test it first, by replacing the `sox` command with `echo`, to see what it's going to do.

```
find . -type f -name "*.wav" -execdir sox {} n_{} silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse \;
```

`find` will find files with matching names, and run the `-execdir` command, after replacing the `{}` in the command with the filename.

Using the plain `-exec` option won't work, because it'd give the file's path, rather than just the filename, so prepending "n_" wouldn't do what you want. For example, it'd turn "./subdir/file.wav" into "n_./subdir/file.wav" rather than "./subdir/n_file.wav". `-execdir` instead does a `cd` into the file's directory, and then runs it with just the filename.

At least, that's what the bsd version that comes with macOS does. The GNU version that Linuxes use seems to put "./" in front of the filename; this usually doesn't matter, but in this case it gives silliness like "n_./file.wav". So test with `echo` first, and make sure it gives the expected filenames.

BTW, I think there are some other versions of `find` that won't substitute the filename in `n_{}` (only with `{}` by itself) in which case this'll fail in yet another way.

Comment: with a tiny adjustment to your answer, I managed it to work. Thanks.

Comment: find . -type f -name "*.wav" -execdir sox {} n_{} silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse \;

Comment: @gurur D'oh! Sorry about missing the `.` parameter -- I was testing under the GNU version (which *doesn't* require that parameter) to see if leaving it off would remove the "./" (it doesn't), and forgot to put it back before copy&pasting the command. I've fixed it for the record.